# Java - A* algorithm ends without expanding any nodes

Tags: java, a-star

I have an assignment to create an A* algorithm through a road graph of the UK through a given template (all files for this assignment I have uploaded [here](https://ufile.io/0rhra)

I think, however, that the problem is somewhere in my Planner.java file - the A* algorithm is not finding a node to expand, it just abruptly stops without expanding any nodes at all.

Here is the code for the Planner :

```
public class Planner implements PlannerInterface<Object> {

// declaration and instantination of our open and closed lists
private final OpenList openList = new OpenList();
private final ArrayList<SearchThroughNodes> closedList;
 public boolean empty() {
    int lengthOfItem = 0;
    return (lengthOfItem == 0);
}       
// constructor of closed list
public Planner() {
    this.closedList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public List<GraphEdge> plan(RoadGraph graph, GraphNode origin, GraphNode destination) {

    // Temporary costs and other data needed
    SearchThroughNodes currentNode, temp1, temp2;
    temp2 = new SearchThroughNodes(null, 0, 0, null);
    GraphNode temp;
    double temporaryCost, heuristics;

    ArrayList<GraphEdge> finalResult; 
    finalResult = new ArrayList<>();

    // check if origin and destination exist a.k.a are not set to null
    boolean originExistence;
    boolean destinationExistence;
    destinationExistence = false;
    originExistence = false;
    if (origin != null && destination != null) {
        originExistence = true;
        destinationExistence = true;
    }

    // Pre-requisites for our A-Star to work

    if (originExistence == true && !destination.equals(origin) && destinationExistence == true ) {
        openList.add(new SearchThroughNodes(origin, 0, Utils.distanceInKM(origin, destination) / 120, null));
    } else {
        return null;
    }




    // A-star loop
    while (!openList.empty()) {

        // Get BEST node to expand

        currentNode = (SearchThroughNodes) openList.get();

        if (closedList.contains(currentNode)) {
            continue;
        } 
        // We reached the destination
        // go back through nodes and read path
        GraphNode checkCurrNode;
        checkCurrNode = currentNode.getGraphNode();
        if (destination.equals(checkCurrNode)) {
            temp1 = currentNode;
            temp2 = (SearchThroughNodes) currentNode.getPrecedingItem();
            while (!temp2.getGraphNode().equals(origin)) {
                finalResult.add(0, graph.getEdge(temp2.getGraphNode().getId(), temp1.getGraphNode().getId()) );
                temp1 = temp2;
                temp2 = (SearchThroughNodes) temp2.getPrecedingItem();
            }
            finalResult.add(0, graph.getEdge(temp2.getGraphNode().getId(), temp1.getGraphNode().getId()));

            return finalResult;
        }


        closedList.add(currentNode);

        long currentNodeId = currentNode.getGraphNode().getId();
        List<GraphEdge> outEdges = graph.getNodeOutcomingEdges(currentNodeId);
        //if expandable
        if (outEdges != null) {
            // traverse all nodes after currentNode
            for (GraphEdge edge : graph.getNodeOutcomingEdges(currentNodeId)) {
                long getFromEdge;
                getFromEdge = edge.getToNodeId();
                //Look at node at the end of the current edge
                temp = graph.getNodeByNodeId(getFromEdge);
                //store nodeID in tmp2 for traversal of openList
                long tmp2GetID;
                tmp2GetID = temp.getId();
                temp2.setNodeID(tmp2GetID);
                // set current edge length in kms,edge max allowed speed and current node cost to variables
                // to later compute the temporary cost
                double edgeLengthInKMs = edge.getLengthInMetres() / 1000;
                double edgeMaxAllowSpeed = edge.getAllowedMaxSpeedInKmph();
                double currCost = currentNode.getCost();
                //new heuristics and cost
                temporaryCost = currCost + edgeLengthInKMs / edgeMaxAllowSpeed;
                heuristics = Utils.distanceInKM(temp, destination) / 120;
                // Proceed here if node wasn't expanded
                if (!closedList.contains(temp2)) {
                    // if node isn't contained currently in closedList
                    // if not,check and update accordingly
                    if (!openList.contains(temp2)) {
                        openList.add(new SearchThroughNodes(temp,
                                temporaryCost, heuristics, currentNode));
                    } else { 
                        temp1 = openList.getNode(temp2);
                        double tempOneCost = temp1.getCost();
                        if (tempOneCost > temporaryCost) {
                            temp1.update(temporaryCost, currentNode);
                        }

                        openList.insert(temp1);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public AbstractOpenList<Object> getOpenList() {
    return openList;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is an `OpenList` what is a `SearchThroughNodes`? And please try to not have so much logic in one method it's really hard to grasp what you are doing (and also testing such methods is a nightmare)

Comment: Also you should step through your code using a debugger to see where your issue exactly occurs.

Comment: I have tried using a debugger but I can't pinpoint any error in my algorithm with it.  `OpenList` is for the currently evaluated node and `SearchThroughNodes` is a class for the traversal of the OpenList ( contains variables like nextItem in the graph,precedingItem and so on). Its all in the files for the assignment.

Comment: 1.) I am surely not going to download a .zip folder from some random upload site on the internet. You should parse code here if it's of interest and you can leave a link to a github repository if it is not of interest but part of the project. Those two classes are of interest so they should be included. If this is too much code you should debug it down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 2.) Use your debugger, step through the loop. At some point you should get to your conditionals that add a value to your `openList`. See why they don't add anything there seemingly. Check for values, what you would expect what they are in reality. Then expand your question with your desired values and what you are experiencing. And then we can help you solve the problem.